# Talend return SQL Server stored procedure (multiple rows/columns)

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, talend

I have a table that has multiple attributes for a person and an sp that returns them. Here is the sample table:

```
create table zpers_dets 
(
    name varchar(max),
    attribute varchar(max),
    value varchar(max)
);

insert into zpers_dets 
values ('abe', 'birth_month', '1'),
       ('abe', 'birth_year', '1999'),
       ('barry', 'birth_month', '3'),
       ('barry', 'birth_year', '1993');
```

I have a stored procedure that takes `@name` as input parameter, and returns all the attribute/value that match:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sppersdata 
    @name varchar(max)
AS
    SELECT attribute, value 
    FROM zpers_dets 
    WHERE name = @name;
```

So, when I run:

```
exec sppersdata @name = N'abe';
```

it returns:

```
Attribute        Value
----------------------
birth_month        1
birth_year        1999
```

2 columns and 2 rows. I'd like to call this stored procedure in Talend OpenStudio Version 7.3.1 and have it return both columns and rows.

How can I configure Talend to take the input parameter (the "@" is not allowed in a Talend schema) and return multiple columns/rows?

Comment: Side notes: are you *really* likely to have people who's names are longer than 8,000 characters? Shame on their parents, if so. Are the names and attributes you're dealing with also *really* likely to be more than 8,000 characters in length? If you have attributes with names over 8,000 characters you really need to think of less verbose names...

Comment: EAV is a well known *bad* design with a lot of drawbacks and no real benefits. You lose indexing, check constraints, easy querying and sorting and *don't gain any flexibility*. In SQL Server you can use up to 32K sparse columns while "bags" of properties can be stored as XML or JSON fields.

Comment: As for `@`, what driver are you using? Some support named parameters, some don't (eg ODBC). If the driver doesn't support named parameters, use `?` to pass positional parameters, eg `SELECT attribute,value FROM zpers_dets WHERE name = ?`

Comment: The issue isn't the size of the fields, it's calling the SP in Talend and returning the multiple columns/rows. As for the "@", this is a sample SP. The one I'm trying to call uses the @, so I was trying to match. I have no choice on the production SP, so what I need are the Talend settings and schemas that will return the columns/rows.

Comment: I already explained how you can call a stored procedure with positional parameters. Did you try that?

Comment: I'm able to call the SP, it's Talend Open Studio, version 7.3.1 that's not returning values. Do you have a link to a solution for TALEND? I've been trying a few I found online, but none of them are working.